# Broke pipe when first line was read

Tags: bash, shell, sh, fish

#### The problem

Need to stop previous commands in pipe when first line received. I.e. stop commands when fifo was closed for input.
I believe there is some shopt..

#### History

Need to send request and get response to/from a simple TCP server.

```
echo $REQUEST | nc localhost 3333  -q3
```

This works fine but always exit after 3 seconds; without `-q3` will never receive response.
And I found nice solution how to close pipe with awk:

```
echo $REQUEST | nc localhost 3333  -q3 | awk '{print;exit}'
```

It works super-nice in FISH but still blocks for a 3 seconds in BASH and SH. *I tested fish, sh, and bash on Ubuntu 16 and MacOS X*

#### Sandbox

For example

```
sh -c  'echo line1; sleep 3; echo NEVER;'  | awk '{print;exit}'
```

I expect to exit immediately, but it sleeps.

**The other way to stop pipeline is `grep '' -m1`**, and it works nice in FISH as awk and doesn't in BASH and SH.

### Workaround

```
mkfifo tempfi
( echo asdf; sleep 9; echo xxa; ) > tempfi &
awk '{print;exit}' <tempfi 
kill $!
```

looks ugly

Comment: What's wrong with `head -n1`?

Comment: `time { read -r line < <(echo asdf; sleep 9; echo xxa); printf '%s\n' "$line"; }` -- `real 0m0.003s`

Comment: @melpomene, ...in order for bash to set `PIPESTATUS`, it needs to wait for every element of the prior pipeline to exit. `time sh -c  'echo line1; sleep 3; echo NEVER;' | head -n1`, there's no `EPIPE` until the attempt to write `NEVER`, so the `sleep` isn't interrupted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, I was just a bit confused by the complicated `awk` and `grep` workarounds for what's essentially just `head`.

Comment: with `nc` why FISH kills pipeline on `awk{exit}` and BASH not? And isn't it possible to make BASH kill pipeline?.

Answer (score 3):

Programs that write to closed pipes find out those pipes closed when their subsequent write receives a `EPIPE` error. If the program sleeps before making a subsequent write (after the point when the reader has consumed all it needs), it thus doesn't receive the EPIPE yet, so it doesn't know to exit yet.

You can avoid worrying about this with a process substitution:

```
read -r line < <(echo asdf; sleep 9; echo xxa)
printf '%s\n' "$line"
```

...does not wait for the subshell running `echo asdf; sleep 9; echo xxa` to exit before going on from the `read` to the `printf`.